# Installation of MSM not working on localhost / server

Tags: multi-site-manager

I have just tried to install Multiple Site Manager (MSM) both on my local MAMP server and on the database.

I have copied the files required, and turned on the MSM setting in General Configuration.

However, whenever I go to "Edit Sites", I get the following error:-

The website encountered an error while retrieving

```
http://localhost:8888/soundhalo-blog/admin.php?S=390e647927cdde75544e6e3c9e258cf84f8cce2b&D=cp&C=sites&M=manage_sites.
```

It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.

Can anyone help me out as to why this is showing up? I get the same error on the server as well.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you set up the admin.php and index.php files in the sub-sites? Its sounds like it could be something to do with the paths to the system folder.

What happens when you visit the subs sites? Do you get an error saying things are configured properly?

Do you have a custom config file running at all? have you got the site turned off?

I have found that when these things happen, that is usually the paths that are wrong. I haven't seen the error you are receiving before.

Do you have admin.php in the root of soundhalo-blog? Have you renamed that file?

I'm sure you've probably read all this, but if you follow the instructions here, you should set it up fine.

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/sites/index.html

Let me know how you get on.